# validation not working properly using jquery request

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `html` form:

```
<form method="POST" action="MyServletName1" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    //Other html code
    <input type="submit" value="Next" onclick="return Check();"/>
</form>
```

Check function is as follows which does simple validation to check whether user has entered id in textfield or not and if user has entered valued in textfield then I am returning true which will submit the above form:

```
function Check()
{
    var myID = document.getElementById('myID').value;
    if(myID!=null && myID.length>0)
        return true;
    else
    {
        alert('Please enter ID!');
        return false;
    }
}
```

The above function works fine. Now I want to check in database whether this ID is already exists or not. And if ID is exist then I don't want to submit the form.

So Now Check() function looks like:

```
function Check()
{
    var myID = document.getElementById('myID').value;
    if(myID!=null && myID.length>0)
    {
        $.post('MyServletName2',{ action: "checkID",myID:myID}).done(function(data) 
        {
            if(data=="OK")
                return true;
            else
            {
                return false;
                alert(data);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        alert('Please enter ID!');
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now if user enters ID then it is sending the request to the servlet, But now form is submitted even if servlet returns other value that `OK`.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: @Downvoter Reason for downvoting will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post is asyncronous. Therefore your method is not returning false until the async post is finished. Because of this your form post is executed normally.

You will probably need to do something else such as changing your input submit to a button. Then your button on callback posts the form skipping the check. Something like...

```
<form method="POST" action="MyServletName1" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form1">
    //Other html code
    <input type="button" value="Next" onclick="Check();"/>
</form>
```

Note i changed the button, added an id to the form `form1` and changed the onlick (removed the return).

The next step is handeling your post. This is a simple change.

```
function Check()
{
    var myID = document.getElementById('myID').value;
    if(myID!=null && myID.length>0)
    {
        $.post('MyServletName2',{ action: "checkID",myID:myID}).done(function(data) 
        {
            if(data=="OK")
                document.getElementById('form1').submit();
            else
            {
                alert(data);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        alert('Please enter ID!');
    }
}
```

Note the only real changes was removing the `return false \ true` and adding the

```
document.getElementById('form1').submit();
```

To submit the form manually.. Now this is just an option, hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

try something like this

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'MyServletName2',
        data : { action: "checkID",myID:myID},
        async: false,
        }).done(function() {
            if(data=="OK"){
                   return true;
            }
               else
               {
                   return false;

               }
        });
```

By default, all requests are sent asynchronously (i.e. this is set to true by default). If you need synchronous requests, set async option to false.

Your form is submited before your ajax get the response so it doesn't validate it.

Answer (score 1):

```
function Check()
{
    var myID = document.getElementById('myID').value;
    var valid = false;
    if (myID != null && myID.length > 0)
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'MyServletName2',
            data: {action: "checkID", myID: myID},
            async: false,
            success: function() {
                if (data == "OK") {
                    valid =  true;
                }
                else
                {
                   valid = false;
                }
            }
        });
        return valid;
    }
    else
    {
        alert('Please enter ID!');
        return false;
    }
}
```